# How can I change the play speed of google bubble chart in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am currently working on my project by using Shiny and google bubble charts.
My project looks very similar to the one in the shiny gallery (https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/google-charts.html). However, my dataset has many more years of data than this demo. I am wondering what argument I can use to increase the play speed from year to year?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sliderInput` has a `animationOptions` feature with default set to 1000ms, just change that.

```
sliderInput(inputId, label, min, max, value, step = NULL,
  round = FALSE, format = NULL, locale = NULL, ticks = TRUE,
  animate = FALSE, width = NULL, sep = ",", pre = NULL,
  post = NULL, timeFormat = NULL, timezone = NULL,
  dragRange = TRUE)

animationOptions(interval = 1000, loop = FALSE, playButton = NULL,
  pauseButton = NULL)
```